# Automatically switch charging lead to highest available connection in a variable series of batteries

Tags: mosfet, battery-charging, lipo

I have a circuit which I use to charge LiPo batteries with a balanced charger. The idea was that I want to charge up to three 2S batteries as one 6S battery without the problems related to simple parallel charging.

To do this I put all cells in series and connect each of them to the balance port of the charger. Then I use a bridge to manually connect "+" to the highest available cell for the main leads. The charger detects the number of cells and adjust the charging voltage automatically. The cells usually charge with 0,3A - 0,6A. Still the charger requires an additional connection between GND and the positive pole of the last cell in series, which is what the bridge is for.

Letting the single cell aspect aside it boils down to GND, S1, S2, S3 and I want to switch automatically to the highest of them based on what is available. So when I plug in the first LiPo the main charging lead needs to be between GND and S1, with two LiPos between GND and S2 and with three between GND and S3.

I think it should be possible to use some MOSFETs to make this automatically. But I have no idea on how to make this dependent on the number of LiPos connected. It would be cool if this would also work for two 3S LiPos or one 2S and one 4S. So basically having automatically the connection to the highest available cell from a maximum of 6 in series.

Any ideas on how to solve this without manual switching?

Comment: Start with  a spec. for thresholds and diagram with SPDT  either going to battery or bypass switch

Comment: Something like this http://tinyurl.com/u3k2b57